# DJANGO | How to update relation nested without validate each foreign key

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, query-optimization

How to update relation nested without validate each foreign key.
Is there a way to avoid validating each foreign key inside a relation list?

```
{
    "name": "Item 0037",
    "price": 10,
    "category":2,
    "prices_list": [
        {
            "id": 192,
            "price_list_id": 1,
            "price": 999.97
        },
        {
            "price_list_id": 2,
            "price": 888.99
        },
        {
            "price_list_id": 2,
            "price": 234.99
        }
    ]       
}
```

I'm using django-rest-framework (serializers, viewset), but every time I send the data I see that it does a validation for each relationship, is there something similar to `fetch_related` that only does a query?

[image]